# Ridge-like alternative for multicollinearity in classification

Tags: logistic, classification, multicollinearity

Multicollinearity affects both regression and classification tasks.

1. OLS is the standard model for regression, while
2. Logistic regression is the standard for classification.

Ridge regression is a penalized version of OLS that treats multicollinearity in regression.

Is there a similar alternative for logistic regression that treats multicollinearity in classification?

Answer (score 1):

There is a unifying framework that encompasses both linear and logistic regression (as well as many other families, e.g., count data modeling through Poisson or negative binomial regression), and also both the lasso and ridge regularization: [elastic net regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization).

The "Software" section of the Wikipedia article gives you pointers to implementations. For instance, the `glmnet` package for R is very well established.

Comment: which logistic regression (classification) model treats multicollinearity? Glmnet does regression, not classification

Comment: (1) *Any* regularization method deals gracefully with multicollinearity, and the elastic net combines two regularization methods, the lasso (L1 penalty) and ridge (L2). (2) The elastic net and [the `glmnet` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) in particular include logistic regression, which can be used for classification. Try `family="binomial"`.

Comment: What ur saying is use the logistic loss combined with an l2 or l1 penalty on the coefficients for classification?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The elastic net gives you a framework for that.